# Active stylus touchscreen options for drawing

Tags: drawing-tablet

I am researching active stylus touchscreen options and think I have a comprehensive list: Wacom, Apple Pencil, Dell Canvas, Microsoft Surface. Are there any that I'm missing?

Although I'm not exactly a graphic designer, my job requires me to draw most of the day (think CAD, hand drawn maps and cross sections). In light of my industry not currently using touchscreens, I am curious if there is a preferred touchscreen for drawing among graphic designers?

I was looking for an active stylus touchscreen with excellent palm rejection, pin point accuracy,  large size ~35", stand-alone monitor (no attached tablet-computer) with cost almost a non-issue. The Wacom Cintiq Pro 32 seems to be the best option but perhaps I've missed something?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why do you need it to be a touchscreen? At least in the past, most people who use drawing tablets haven't really cared about touch features... unless they are like super into finger painting. The only real upside I can think of is rotating the canvas with your fingers, but for years people have been doing that via shortcuts or like pressing a button in the pen and using the pen itself to rotate the canvas. That said... You can't really go wrong with Cintiq... especially if the price tag doesn't really matter.

Comment: Honestly if you do precision work (as it is CAD drawing) the last thing you'd need would be a touchscreen. Unless you are into finger painting in your spare time.

Comment: I think this is a bit too opinion based for the site, but..... emphasizing @joonas ' comment.. ... You can't really go wrong with Cintiq.....

Comment: Huion has some really nice options for the pen/monitor and drawing tablet options. And they are pretty well priced. Might be an option if you're not looking for the highest end tablet available.